# What are the openings that are popular among club players, but are (more or less) rejected by modern professional players?

Tags: opening

For example, I see club players playing King's Gambit as well as the Four Knights Game a lot but almost never see these openings in the games of modern professional players.

Are there other openings that are popular among club players but more or less rejected by professional players?

Comment: Just a comment because I don't have stats easily accessible, but the openings that come to my mind are the Benko (by medium-to-strong amateurs), the Blackmar-Diemer and the Morra gambit (by less strong amateurs).

Comment: The Orangutan (1. b4)...though Magnus rolled that out last year for a surprise victory.

Comment: This must be a large list. The Danish gambit and the Latvian gambit come to mind, although I am not sure how popular they are on the club level.

Comment: BenOni, Dutch and Scandinavian openings are also much more common at club level than at GM level.

Comment: almost all gambits except queens gambit? :D

Comment: I corrected for bad grammar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach that I did. Collect opening and variation names take the fen and search the stats of this opening. The opening is taken from [eco.pgn from pgn-extract.](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/) Then use the [opening explorer of lichess api](https://lichess.org/api#tag/Opening-Explorer) to get the white wins, draws and black wins and finally the total games.

In this example the total games determines the popularity of the opening. The most number of games is ranked number 1. I used two databases, the lichess database and the masters database. If the move is not found in the database then its rank is set 100. Also for a given fen the number of moves requested from api is 20. So if fen is from start position + e4 move, the stats of reply moves requested is 20, can be e5, e6, c5 ... until 20 only.

The following are the results after checking the first 500 out of 2000 plus openings in the eco.pgn. The game coverage is from 2012-01 to 2021-11 applied to both lichess and masters databases.

`rank_lcp` is the ranking by number of games of the move based from lichess database rating groups of 1600, 1800 and 2000 with classical rating, move with most games is ranked #1

`rank_mast` is the ranking by number of games based from the masters database, move with most games is ranked #1.

`lcp_pop` is the difference between rank_mast and rank_lcp move, if this is positive that means it is popular to lichess players compared to masters, the value 100 as rank means it is not found in the given database,

`fen` is the position before the last move in the eco.pgn.

`move` is the last move in the eco.pgn

`opening and variation` are the names after making the move and are also available from the eco.pgn.

Example, in index 36 is bird opening with variation name `From gambit, Lipke variation` the fen is `rnbqk2r/ppp2ppp/3b3n/8/8/5N2/PPPPP1PP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 2 5` and the move is d4. Based on lichess classical database with 1600, 1800, 2000 lichess ratings, the move d4 is ranked #1 whereas that move is not found in masters database with rank 100, resulting in 100-1 or 99 lcp_pop value.

Be noted that there are moves from lichess masters database with rank 100 meaning not found because the masters database moves included are only from 2012 to 2021-11. It is possible that if I change it to 1952 to 2021 range, that move can be in the master database. See second pastebin link for comparison from the full masters database.

The results below are only those openings having positive lcp_pop.

#### 1. Lichess classical rating group 1600, 1800, 2000 database against lichess masters database, year range: {lichess: 2012 to 2021-11, masters: 2012 to 2021-11}

```
                                         opening                                                     variaton                                                                      fen   move  rank_lcp  rank_mast  lcp_pop
0                                         Vienna                               Hamppe-Muzio, Dubois variation            r1bqkbnr/pppp1p1p/8/4n3/2B1PQ2/2N5/PPPP2PP/R1B2RK1 b kq - 0 8    Qf6         1        100       99
1                                            KGD                                Falkbeer, Charousek variation            rnb1kb1r/ppp3pp/8/3q1p2/4nP2/8/PPPNQ1PP/R1B1KBNR w KQkq - 0 8     g4         1        100       99
2                                            KGA                             bishop's gambit, Greco variation              rnb1kbnr/pppp1ppp/8/8/2B1Pp1q/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQ1KNR b kq - 3 4    Bc5         1        100       99
3                                            KGA                           bishop's gambit, classical defence           rnb1k1nr/pppp1pbp/8/6p1/2BPPp1q/2N5/PPP3PP/R1BQ1KNR b kq - 0 6    Ne7         1        100       99
4                                            KGA                            bishop's gambit, McDonnell attack            rnb1k2r/ppppnpbp/8/6p1/2BPPp1q/2N5/PPP3PP/R1BQ1KNR w kq - 1 7     g3         1        100       99
5                                      Ruy Lopez                                Berlin defence, Mortimer trap         r1bqkb1r/ppppnppp/5n2/1B2N3/4P3/3P4/PPP2PPP/RNBQK2R b KQkq - 0 5     c6         1        100       99
6                                            KGA                               Cunningham, three pawns gambit              rnbqk1nr/pppp1ppp/8/8/2B1P2b/5N2/PPPP3p/RNBQ1RK1 w kq - 0 7    Kh1         1        100       99
7                                   Queen's pawn                                               Englund gambit         r1b1kbnr/ppppq1pp/2n2P2/3Q4/8/5N2/PPP1PPPP/RNB1KB1R b KQkq - 0 5   Nxf6         1        100       99
8                                         Petrov                          modern attack, Bardeleben variation           rnbqkb1r/pppp1ppp/8/2n1P3/3N4/8/PPP1QPPP/RNB1KB1R b KQkq - 0 6    Nc6         1        100       99
9                                            KGA                                      Allgaier, Horny defence              rnbq1b1r/pppp1k2/5n1p/8/4PQ1P/8/PPPP2P1/RNB1KB1R b KQ - 0 8    Bd6         1        100       99
10                                           KGA                                     Allgaier, Cook variation                rnbq1bnr/ppp3k1/7p/8/2BPpBpP/8/PPP3P1/RN1QK2R w KQ - 2 10   Be5+         1        100       99
11                                  Evans gambit                                           Steinitz variation       r1bqk1nr/ppp3pp/1b1p1p2/n5B1/2BPP3/2N2N2/P4PPP/R2Q1RK1 w kq - 0 11    Be3         1        100       99
12                                           KGA                                      Allgaier, Urusov attack                rnbq1bnr/ppp3k1/7p/3B4/4PppP/8/PPPP2P1/RNBQK2R w KQ - 1 9     d4         1        100       99
13                    Blackburne shilling gambit                                                          NaN                r1b1kbnr/pppp1Npp/8/8/3nq3/8/PPPPBP1P/RNBQKR2 b Qkq - 1 7   Nf3#         1        100       99
14                                           KGA           Kieseritsky, long whip defence, Jaenisch variation           rnbqk1n1/pppp1p1r/7b/4N2p/2BPPppP/8/PPP3P1/RNBQK2R w KQq - 1 8    Nc3         1        100       99
15                                  Four knights                  Rubinstein counter-gambit Maroczy variation       r1bq1rk1/ppp2ppp/3p1n2/2b1p3/N3P3/3P1B2/PPP2PPP/R1BQ1RK1 b - - 1 9    Bb6         1        100       99
16                                           KGA                                Kieseritsky, Brentano defence          rnbqkb1r/ppp2p1p/5n2/3pN3/3PPppP/8/PPP3P1/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 1 7   Bxf4         1        100       99
17                                           KGA                 Kieseritsky, Salvio defence, Cozio variation            rnb1kbnr/ppppq2p/8/4Np2/3PPppP/8/PPP3P1/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 7    Bc4         1        100       99
18                                       Latvian                                            Polerio variation             rnbqkbnr/pppp2pp/8/4N3/2B1p3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R b KQkq - 0 4     d5         1        100       99
19                                            KP                            Nimzovich defence, Wheeler gambit            r1bqkbnr/pppppppp/2n5/8/4P3/2P5/P2P1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 1 4     d4         1        100       99
20                                  Scandinavian                     Anderssen counter-attack orthodox attack          r1b1k1nr/ppp2ppp/2n5/q3P3/1b6/2N5/PPPB1PPP/R2QKBNR w KQkq - 3 7    Nf3         1        100       99
21                                        Scotch                                               Sea-cadet mate              r2q1bnr/ppp1kBpp/3p4/4N3/4P3/2N5/PP3PPP/R1Bb1RK1 w - - 1 10   Nd5#         1        100       99
22       Ponziani counter-gambit, Schmidt attack                                                          NaN        r1bqkbnr/ppp3pp/2np4/4pp2/3PP3/2P2N2/PP3PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 5     d5         1        100       99
23                            Alekhine's defence                                              Kmoch variation         rnbqkb1r/pp1ppppp/1n6/2p1P3/8/1B6/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 5     d3         1        100       99
24                                      Philidor                                               Paulsen attack              rnbqkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3p4/3NP3/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 5   exd5         1        100       99
25                                        Petrov                              classical attack, Marshall trap        rn1q1rk1/ppp3pp/3b4/3P1p2/3Pn1b1/3B1N2/PP3PPP/RNBQR1K1 b - - 1 10  Bxh2+         1        100       99
26                            Alekhine's defence                       four pawns attack, Ilyin-Genevsky var.         r2qkb1r/ppp1p1pp/1nn1p3/8/2PP2b1/5N2/PP4PP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 9     c5         1        100       99
27                                     Ruy Lopez                                         Rabinovich variation        r1bqk2r/2p2ppp/p4n2/1pbPR1N1/3n4/1B6/PPPP1PPP/RNBQ2K1 b kq - 0 10    Kf8         1        100       99
28                        Irish (Chicago) gambit                                                          NaN             r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4n3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 4     d4         1        100       99
29                                           KGD                                   Falkbeer, Alapin variation              rnb1k2r/ppp2ppp/8/3q4/4nP2/5N2/PPP1QbPP/RNBK1B1R w kq - 0 9   Nfd2         1        100       99
30                                     Gruenfeld                                     Russian, Keres variation        r2q1rk1/ppp1ppbp/1nn3p1/8/3PP1b1/2NQBN2/PP2BPPP/R3K2R w KQ - 7 11  O-O-O         1        100       99
31                              Bishop's opening                                              Pratt variation           rnbqk2r/ppp2ppp/5P2/2b4Q/2pp4/2P5/PP3PPP/RNB1K1NR b KQkq - 1 7    O-O         1        100       99
32                                           QGD                            Albin counter-gambit, Lasker trap          rnbqk1nr/ppp2ppp/8/4P3/1bPp4/4P3/PP1B1PPP/RN1QKBNR b KQkq - 2 5   dxe3         1        100       99
33                                     Ruy Lopez                                  closed, Leonhardt variation   rnb1k2r/2q1bppp/p2p1n2/1ppPp3/4P3/2P2N1P/PPBN1PP1/R1BQR1K1 b kq - 2 13     g5         1        100       99
34                Vienna gambit, Wurzburger trap                                                          NaN           rnb1kb1r/ppp2ppp/8/3pP2q/8/2NP1Nn1/PPP4P/R1BQKB1R w KQkq - 2 8   Nxd5         1        100       99
35                              Amsterdam attack                                                          NaN       r1bqkbnr/ppp2ppp/2np4/4p3/2P5/1PN1P3/P2P1PPP/R1BQKBNR b KQkq - 0 4    Nf6         1        100       99
36                                          Bird                                 From gambit, Lipke variation              rnbqk2r/ppp2ppp/3b3n/8/8/5N2/PPPPP1PP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 2 5     d4         1        100       99
37                                     Ruy Lopez                                              Noah's ark trap         r1bqk2r/2p1bppp/p2p1n2/1p6/3QP3/1B6/PPP2PPP/RNB1R1K1 b kq - 0 10     c5         1        100       99
38                                       Catalan                                   closed, Sokolsky variation       r1bq1rk1/3nbppp/1pp1pn2/p2p4/2PP4/1P3NP1/PBQNPPBP/R4RK1 b - - 1 10    Ba6         1        100       99
39                                   Amar gambit                                                          NaN             rn1qkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3pp3/5P2/6PB/PPPPP2P/RNBQK2R b KQkq - 0 4   exf4         1        100       99
40                                    Old Indian                                    Dus-Khotimirsky variation      r1bqkb1r/pppn1ppp/3p1n2/4p3/2PP4/2N1P3/PP3PPP/R1BQKBNR w KQkq - 1 5    Bd3         2        100       98
41                                      Budapest                            Alekhine variation, Balogh gambit           rnbqkb1r/pppp1ppp/8/4P3/2P1P1n1/8/PP3PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 4     d6         2        100       98
42                                  Evans gambit                                               Goering attack         r1bqk1nr/ppp2ppp/1b1p4/n7/2BPP3/2N2N2/P4PPP/R1BQ1RK1 w kq - 3 10    Bg5         2        100       98
43                                           KGA                                      Allgaier, Walker attack                rnbq1bnr/pppp1k2/7p/8/4PppP/8/PPPP2P1/RNBQKB1R w KQ - 0 7   Bc4+         2        100       98
44                             Giuoco Pianissimo                                             Dubois variation      r1bqk1nr/pppp2pp/2n5/2b1ppN1/2B1P3/3P4/PPP2PPP/RNBQK2R b KQkq - 1 5     f4         2        100       98
45                                           KGD                                   Falkbeer, Charousek gambit               rnbqkb1r/ppp2ppp/8/3P4/4nP2/8/PPP3PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 6    Qe2         2        100       98
46                             Fried fox defence                                                          NaN             rnbqkbnr/ppppp1pp/5p2/8/3PP3/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 2    Kf7         2        100       98
47                                           KGA                Kieseritsky, Brentano defence, Caro variation            rnbqkb1r/ppp2p1p/8/3pN3/3PnBpP/8/PPP3P1/RN1QKB1R w KQkq - 0 8    Nd2         2        100       98
48                                  Four knights                                          Spielmann variation            r3kb1r/1pp2ppp/p1p1b3/4q3/3PN3/8/PPP2PPP/R1BQR1K1 b kq - 0 10    Qd5         2        100       98
49                                           KGA                                     Kieseritsky, Rice gambit         rnbqk2r/ppp2p1p/3b1n2/3PN3/2B2ppP/8/PPPP2P1/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 1 8    O-O         2        100       98
50                                  Giuoco Piano                                             Krause variation              r1bq3r/ppp3pp/5k2/3pN3/1n1Pn3/1Q6/PP3PPP/RN2K2R w KQ - 2 12     f3         2        100       98
51                                            KP                           Nimzovich defence, Marshall gambit            r1b1kbnr/ppp1pppp/2n5/3q4/3P4/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 4    Nc3         2        100       98
52                                      Philidor                      Philidor counter-gambit, del Rio attack             rnbqkbnr/ppp3pp/8/3pP1N1/4p3/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 6     e6         2        100       98
53                                 Scotch gambit                                           Hanneken variation           r1bq1rk1/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4P1N1/1bB5/8/PB3PPP/RN1Q1RK1 b - - 0 9   Nxe5         2        100       98
54                                  Nimzo-Indian                                Spielmann, San Remo variation    r1bqk2r/pp1p1ppp/2n1p3/2P5/1bP1n3/1QN2N2/PP1BPPPP/R3KB1R b KQkq - 4 7   Nxc5         2        100       98
55                                        Vienna                           Steinitz gambit, Zukertort defence          r1b1kbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/8/3PPp1q/2N5/PPP1K1PP/R1BQ1BNR b kq - 2 5     d5         2        100       98
56                                           KGA                                              Allgaier gambit            rnbqkbnr/pppp1p1p/8/8/4PppP/5N2/PPPP2P1/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 5    Ng5         2        100       98
57                                           QGD                                            Rochlin variation   r1b1kb1r/pp1n1ppp/2p1pn2/q2p2B1/2PP4/2N2N2/PP2PPPP/2RQKB1R w Kkq - 2 7    Bd2         2        100       98
58                                  Giuoco Piano                                          Bernstein variation             r1bqk2r/pppp1ppp/2n5/8/2BP4/1Qb2N2/P4PPP/R1B2RK1 b kq - 1 10     d5         2        100       98
59                                     Ruy Lopez               Steinitz defence deferred, Lipnitsky variation         r1bqkb1r/2p2ppp/p1pp1n2/4p3/3PP3/5N2/PPP2PPP/RNBQ1RK1 b kq - 0 7    Bg4         2        100       98
60                                           KGA                                    Cunningham, Bertin gambit           rnbqk1nr/pppp1ppp/8/8/2B1Pp1b/5N2/PPPP2PP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 5     g3         2        100       98
61                                           KGA                                         Silberschmidt gambit            rnb1kb1r/pppp1p1p/7n/4N3/2BPPppq/8/PPP3PP/RNBQ1K1R b kq - 0 7     f3         2        100       98
62                                     Ruy Lopez                         Berlin defence, Trifunovic variation          r1bqk2r/ppppbppp/2n5/1B2p3/3Pn3/5N2/PPP1QPPP/RNB2RK1 b kq - 2 6     d5         2        100       98
63                           two knights defence                                            Maroczy variation        r1bqkb1r/ppp2pp1/5n1p/3P4/2P1p3/5N2/PPP1QPPP/RNB1K2R b KQkq - 0 9    Be7         2        100       98
64                                        French                                           Steinitz variation         rnbqkb1r/pp1n1ppp/4p3/2PpP3/5P2/2N5/PPP3PP/R1BQKBNR b KQkq - 0 6    Nc6         2        100       98
65                                           QGD  Tarrasch, Schlechter-Rubinstein system, Rey Ardid variation        r1bqkbnr/pp3ppp/2n5/3p4/2pP4/2N2NP1/PP2PP1P/R1BQKB1R w KQkq - 0 7     e4         2        100       98
66        Two knights defence, Keidanz variation                                                          NaN             r1bqk2r/ppp2ppp/2N5/1B1pP3/4n3/8/PPP2bPP/RNBQ1K1R b kq - 1 9    Qh4         2        100       98
67                                     Ruy Lopez                                      open, Richter variation        r1bqkb1r/2pp1ppp/p1n5/1p2p3/B2Pn3/5N2/PPP2PPP/RNBQ1RK1 w kq - 0 7     d5         2        100       98
68                                  Giuoco Piano                                             Aitken variation             r1bqk2r/pppp1ppp/2n5/8/2BP4/2b2N2/P4PPP/R1BQ1RK1 w kq - 0 10    Ba3         2        100       98
69                                      Philidor                 Philidor counter-gambit, Zukertort variation          rnbqkbnr/ppp3pp/3p4/4pp2/3PP3/5N2/PPP2PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 4    Nc3         3        100       97
70                                           KGD                                     Falkbeer, Reti variation           rnbqkb1r/ppp2ppp/5n2/3P4/4pP2/3P4/PPP3PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 1 5    Qe2         3        100       97
71                              Bishop's opening                                           Lisitsyn variation                  r2qkbnr/pp3ppp/8/3pn3/8/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 8    Ne2         3        100       97
72                                 King's Indian                         Four pawns attack, Florentine gambit      rnbq1rk1/pp3pbp/3p1np1/2pp4/2P1PP2/2N2N2/PP2B1PP/R1BQK2R w KQ - 0 9     e5         3        100       97
73                                     Ruy Lopez                          Berlin defence, Pillsbury variation               r1bqk2r/pnppbppp/2p5/4P3/8/5N2/PPP1QPPP/RNB2RK1 w kq - 1 9     b3         3        100       97
74                                           QGD                       Orthodox defence, Capablanca variation        r1bq1rk1/p1pnbppp/1p3n2/3p2B1/3P4/2N1PN2/PP3PPP/2RQKB1R w K - 0 9    Bb5         3        100       97
75                                       Latvian                                     corkscrew counter-gambit             rnbqkbnr/pppp2pp/8/4N3/2B1p3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R b KQkq - 0 4    Nf6         3        100       97
76                                           KGD                             classical, Soldatenkov variation        rnbqk1nr/ppp2ppp/3p4/2b1p3/4PP2/5N2/PPPP2PP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 4   fxe5         3        100       97
77                                           KGA                         bishop's gambit, Anderssen variation              rnbqkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3B4/4Pp2/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQK1NR b KQkq - 0 4     c6         3        100       97
78                                  Giuoco Piano                                      Ghulam Kassim variation              r1bqk2r/pppp1ppp/2n5/2bBP3/8/2p2N2/PP3KPP/RNBQ3R w kq - 0 9    Kg3         3        100       97
79                                 Scotch gambit                                               Vitzhum attack         r1bqk2r/pppp1ppp/2n4n/2b3N1/2BpP3/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 6    Qh5         3        100       97
80                                        Scotch                                         Gottschall variation              1rb2rk1/pp3ppp/2n2q2/3P4/8/2P1Q3/PP3PPP/RN2KB1R b KQ - 0 12    Nb4         3        100       97
81                                           KGA                             Lolli gambit (wild Muzio gambit)           rnbqkbnr/pppp1p1p/8/8/2B1Ppp1/5N2/PPPP2PP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 0 5  Bxf7+         3        100       97
82                                           KGD                               classical, Svenonius variation   r2qk2r/ppp2ppp/2np1n2/2b1p3/2B1PP2/2NP1Q1P/PPP3P1/R1B1K2R b KQkq - 0 8   exf4         3        100       97
83                                           QGD                              Semi-Tarrasch, Krause variation       rnbqkb1r/1p3ppp/p4n2/1N1pp1B1/2P5/2N5/PP2PPPP/R2QKB1R w KQkq - 0 8    Qa4         3        100       97
84                                           KGA                                  Allgaier, Thorold variation                rnbq1bnr/pppp1k2/7p/8/4PppP/8/PPPP2P1/RNBQKB1R w KQ - 0 7     d4         3        100       97
85                                   two knights                           Max Lange attack, Berger variation          r3k2r/ppp2ppp/1bn1bPq1/6N1/2ppNPP1/8/PPP4P/R1BQR1K1 b kq - 0 13  O-O-O         3        100       97
86                                      Sicilian                          dragon, classical, Stockholm attack            r4rk1/pp2ppbp/3p1np1/q4P2/4P3/2N1B3/PPP1Q1PP/R4RK1 w - - 0 14     g4         3        100       97
87                                  Four knights                                           Marshall variation       r1bq1rk1/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/1Bb1N3/4P3/2N5/PPPP1PPP/R1BQ1RK1 b - - 0 6    Nd4         3        100       97
88                                           KGA                                              Herzfeld gambit            rnb1kbnr/pppp1p1p/8/4N3/2B1Pppq/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQ1K1R b kq - 3 6    Nc6         3        100       97
89                                 Vienna gambit                                              Heyde variation         rnbqkb1r/ppp3pp/8/3pPp2/4n3/2N2Q2/PPPP2PP/R1B1KBNR w KQkq f6 0 6     d4         3        100       97
90                                           QGD                                exchange, chameleon variation         r1bqrnk1/ppp1bppp/5n2/3p2B1/3P4/2NBP3/PPQ1NPPP/R3K2R w KQ - 7 10  O-O-O         3        100       97
91    Hammerschlag (Fried fox/Pork chop opening)                                                          NaN             rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/8/5P2/PPPPP1PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2    Kf2         3        100       97
92                                  Four knights                                          Svenonius variation      r1bq1rk1/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/1B2p3/4P3/2PP1N2/P1P2PPP/R1BQ1RK1 b - - 0 7     d5         3        100       97
93                                           KGD                             Falkbeer, Milner-Barry variation             rnbqkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3pp3/4PP2/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 3    Nc3         4        100       96
94                                           KGA                                  Allgaier, Blackburne gambit                rnbq1bnr/pppp1k2/7p/8/4PppP/8/PPPP2P1/RNBQKB1R w KQ - 0 7    Nc3         4        100       96
95                                   Centre game                                         Kupreichik variation         r1bqr1k1/ppp2ppp/2np1n2/8/1bB1P3/2N1Q3/PPPB1PPP/2KR2NR w - - 0 9    Nh3         4        100       96
96                              Bishop's opening                                     MacDonnell double gambit          rnbqk1nr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/1bB1P3/8/P1PP1PPP/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 4     f4         4        100       96
97                                     Caro-Kann                             Panov-Botvinnik, Gunderam attack             rnbqkb1r/pp2pppp/5n2/3p4/2PP4/8/PP3PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 1 5     c5         4        100       96
98                                           KGA                                         Ghulam Kassim gambit           rnbqkbnr/pppp1p1p/8/8/2B1Ppp1/5N2/PPPP2PP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 0 5     d4         4        100       96
99                                        Vienna                                      Zhuravlev countergambit       rnbqk1nr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/1b2P1Q1/2N5/PPPP1PPP/R1B1KBNR b KQkq - 3 3    Nf6         4        100       96
100                                          KGD                                    Falkbeer, Keres variation           rnbqkb1r/ppp2ppp/5n2/3P4/4pP2/3P4/PPP3PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 1 5    Nd2         4        100       96
101                                      Latvian                                          Nimzovich variation            rnb1kbnr/ppp3pp/3p1q2/8/2NPp3/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 6    Ne3         4        100       96
102                                       Petrov                            modern attack, Steinitz variation           rnbqkb1r/pppp1ppp/8/4P3/3pn3/5N2/PPP2PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 1 5    Qe2         4        100       96
103                                Greco defence                                                          NaN           rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2    Qf6         4        100       96
104                                          KGA                                                 Greco gambit           rnbqk1nb/pp3p2/2pp4/6p1/2BPPp2/2N2N2/PPP3P1/R1BQK3 w Qq - 0 10    Ne5         4        100       96
105                           Alekhine's defence                         two pawns' attack, Mikenas variation       rnbqkb1r/pppp1ppp/4p3/2PnP3/2B5/2N5/PP1P1PPP/R1BQK1NR b KQkq - 1 6     d6         4        100       96
106                                 Evans gambit                        compromised defence, Potter variation         r1b1k2r/ppppnppp/2n3q1/b3P3/2B5/1QN2N2/P4PPP/R1B2RK1 w kq - 1 11    Rd1         4        100       96
107                                 Crab opening                                                          NaN              rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/P7/8/1PPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2     h4         4        100       96
108                               Tayler opening                                                          NaN        r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPPBPPP/RNBQK2R w KQkq - 4 4     d4         4        100       96
109                                          QGD                          Lasker defence, Bernstein variation             rnb2rk1/ppp1qpp1/7p/3p4/3P4/1QP1PN2/P4PPP/R3KB1R b KQ - 1 11    Qd6         4        100       96
```

All 2014 openings in the eco.pgn are checked and there are only 502 openings where a move is more popular in lichess classical rating group 1600, 1800, 2000 database compared to lichess masters database.

All results cannot be shown because of message box character limit. The full [502 results](https://pastebin.com/raw/tqi1EfQM) can be found at pastebin.

#### 2. Lichess classical rating group 1600, 1800, 2000 database against lichess masters database, year range: {lichess: 2012 to 2021-11, masters: 1952 to 2021-11}

Full result is in [pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/raw/QfrtWXEw)

#### 3. Lichess rapid rating group 1600, 1800, 2000 database against lichess masters database, year range: {lichess: all available as of 2022-05-17, masters: 1952 to 2021-11}

It includes eco and main line moves.

Full result is in [pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/4NpUASYc)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer the question the other way around. There are thousands of trappy lines an amateur might play but the number of lines a professional might play is very small.

For example, with white, you only really have the Ruy Lopez, Queens gambit and English. Maybe the Catalan. White might play 1nf3 or 1g3 but those are only attempts to transpose into favorable lines either in the above mentioned openings or to some pet line.

Some openings like the Scotch or London are viable but probably equal and are actually usually more popular at amateur level.

With black vs e4 there are 10 reasonable responses but only 4 (e5,c5,e6,c6,) are played often by professionals.